# A better way to use Stored Procedures in ASP.NET?

Tags: stored-procedures, orm, ado.net, code-generation

I'm currently employed at a small ASP.NET/MS-SQL shop. My team has noticed that a very large amount of our development (and bugfixing) time is spent on our ADO.NET Database Access code. We're looking for a software solution that eases the process of mapping the DataTable/SQLDataReader results to proper business objects. Manually specifying column names and casting the results is becoming a nightmare (especially when schema changes are involved).

So far, Entity Framework (and to a lesser extent, LINQ-to-SQL) has been the only piece of software we've found that automates this process fairly well. We simply add our stored procedures to the model and let them return auto-generated Complex Types. The ability to update the model from the database is also a big plus.

Before we start migrating any of our many projects to Entity Framework, I was wondering if there are any other options that we should look at. My team has no strong preference between ORM libraries or Code Generators.

Some of the criteria that might help:

1. All data access (including CRUD) is performed through Stored Procedures on SQL Server 2008R2. **Please don't answer "stop using stored procedures"**. An ORM would make an incredible amount of sense in our situation, but our DBA's decision trumps the programming team's.
2. Software should help with resolving SPROC parameter names and with converting the result into some strongly typed object we can work with.
3. We're an academic institution with a very small budget. We've pretty much expended our budget this year (we got Resharper licenses - thankfully at a reduced price), so commercial solutions with a hefty price tag are out.
4. We are not able to use GPL libraries. LGPL/BSD or anything similar are fine
5. We're looking to make things easier for our developers. Moving the column/type information from C# to manually-written XML doesn't really make their jobs any easier. We're looking for something as automated as possible.

Comment: "An ORM would make an incredible amount of sense in our situation, but our DBA's decision trumps the programming team's" - is that a Business decision, or just the DBA's say?

Comment: Use **Entity Framework 4** (.NET 4) - it supports stored procedures really well - for any operation! (most other ORM don't even begin to try to do so....)

Comment: @marc_s: Which ORMs are you thinking of that don't support stored procedures?  I can't think of one that matters off the top of my head.

Comment: The fact will remain that using stored procedures from code is significantly more challenging than using dynamic SQL from code.  I understand that's not really an option for you and that's very unfortunate.  DBAs shouldn't be allowed to dictate this kind of stuff.  If I were in your shoes, I would focus on the DBA problem, not the apparent technical problem.

Comment: There are no business reasons for the sprocs. Reading through stored procedure code is easier/faster for our DBA than looking at queries being run in SQL Management Studio... We have 8 programmers that support a total of about 90 small and 25 medium sized webapps. Most apps have a user base of about 10 people. Our SQL is 95% CRUD. Only our custom web portal uses this database. Frequently changing requirements lead to frequent db schema changes. None of our apps are database intensive, none are high security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should seriously take a look at the Type Map OR/M & generator from Software is Hardwork Library at:

http://code.google.com/p/softwareishardwork/

Comment: Above link is stale: the project was forked into a code generator/text templating project called TextMetal by me.

http://code.google.com/p/textmetal/

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'm a fan of [iBatis.NET](http://ibatis.apache.org/) when stuck in this situation.  As far as I know, it's no longer in development, but its successor [MyBatis](http://www.mybatis.org/) may be a good option as well.